# JGit not deleting my file after I deleted from the local repository

Tags: java, git, jgit

How can I delete a file using JGit?

I deleted from the local repository and I commited-pushed the changes but seems like JGit did not noticed that it has been deleted. It still exists in the remote repository.

the function I call to commit changes:

```
public void commitChanges(){
    Git git = null;
    try {                   
            git = Git.open(new File("./TestGitRepository/.git") );
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {       
            git.add().addFilepattern(".").call();
        } catch (NoFilepatternException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (GitAPIException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // Now, we do the commit with a message
        try {
            RevCommit revCommit= git.commit().setMessage("commit try").call();
        } catch (GitAPIException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
    } 
    git.getRepository().close();
}
```

the function I call to push the changes:

```
public void pushLocalChanges(){         
    Repository localRepo = null;
    try {
        localRepo = new FileRepository("./TestGitRepository/.git");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Git git = new Git(localRepo);
    PushCommand push = git.push();
    UsernamePasswordCredentialsProvider user = new UsernamePasswordCredentialsProvider("userName", "password");
    push.setCredentialsProvider(user);
    push.setRemote(REMOTE_URL);
    try {
         push.call();
        System.out.println ("pushed to upstream: "+push.getReceivePack());
    } catch (GitAPIException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    git.getRepository().close();    
}
```

Nothing is changing on the remote repository, What have I missed?
Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: If you feel an answer solved the problem, including answers given by yourself, please mark it as 'accepted' by clicking the green check mark. This helps keep the focus on older posts which still don't have answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This solve it for me:

```
 git.pull();
 git.rm().addFilepattern("fileToDelete").call();
 commitChanges()
 pushLocalChanges()
```

Answer (score 4):

`git.rm().addFilepattern("fileToDelete").call();` will only delete the files that are explicitly mentioned as the argument to addFilepattern().

Ideally, it should automatically delete all files that have been deleted from the local repo. And it can be done by using *add().setUpdate(true)* as shown below:-

```
            git.add().setUpdate(true).addFilepattern(".").call();
            git.commit().setMessage("delete files").call();
            RefSpec spec = new RefSpec("refs/heads/master:refs/remotes/branch1");
            git.push().setRemote("origin").setRefSpecs(spec).call();
```

Comment: Thanks. Combining this with `git.add().addFilepattern(".").call();` replicates the standard `git add` command line behaviour of adding removing changed files correctly.

Answer (score 4):

Be inspired by the people above, I've solved it. The following is my code:

```java
/**
 * 添加且提交全部
 * 同等于 git add . && git commit -m 'some msg'
 * @param repoDir 仓库地址
 * @param msg 消息
 */
public static void addAndCommitAll(File repoDir, String msg) throws IOException, GitAPIException {
    try(Git git=Git.open(repoDir)){
        //全部添加, 除了.gitignore文件中指定的
        doAddAll(git);
        //全部提交
        git.commit()
                .setMessage(msg)
                .call();
    }
}

/**
 * 添加全部
 * 相当于 git add .
 * @param repoDir 仓库地址
 */
 public static void addAll(File repoDir) throws IOException, GitAPIException {
     try(Git git=Git.open(repoDir)){
         doAddAll(git);
     }
 }

 private static void doAddAll(Git git) throws GitAPIException {
     //add removed and modified file
     git.add()
             .setUpdate(true)
             .addFilepattern(".")
             .call();
     //add new and modified file
     git.add()
             .addFilepattern(".")
             .call();
 }
```

Comment: This is a better answer if files are deleted externally and has untracked files to be added as well as some deleted.